# What type of Data Relationships would I use for setting up 3 tables and connect to them

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run a query that would SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE users.school = teachers.school AND WHERE users.grade = teachers.grade.

I'm setting up three tables, users, teachers and schools. The users are the parents and admins at the school, they sign up with an access_code that matches up in the school table. Same for the teachers, but their info is stored in the teacher's table. (Each user and teacher are associated with a school and grade both are in their tables). I want to show the user all the teachers info at the users' school.

I have all the info for the schools table `id`, `school`, and `access_codes`, but how would I go about achieving this? Would I use a JOIN or FOREIGN KEY?

I've tried some JOIN's, but I'm not that familiar with them. I looked at the FOREIGN KEY but not sure how to use it. Any help would be very much appreciated .

Comment: Hi Edward.  This question could use an [edit] (please click that) to your details with a bit of sample data from each table (anonymized as necessary), along with the attempts you've made in SQL queries so far.

Answer (score 0):

foreign key if for constarints
for build the relation you can use join  eg:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM teachers 
 INNER JOIN users ON  users.school = teachers.school 
  AND users.grade = teachers.grade
```

Anyway  in you pseudo code  you have only two table  `teachers` and `users`

Answer (score 0):

I kind a found a work around to my problem

```
  SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE school = 
    (
      SELECT school FROM users WHERE id = ".$id = $_SESSION['id']."
    )
  GROUP BY grade
```

This is a start it's not perfect but if I add another session for `grade` I think it will work.